# Laravel: How to push a model into a variable?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, push

I am trying to recover product data from a left-right category tree.

This is my code so far:

```
$branches = Category::whereBetween('left', array($category->left, $category->right))
    ->get();

foreach ($branches as $branch) {
    $products = $branch->product;
}
```

How can I make a += or push operation to $products in order to get all the products of every branch?

Thank you very much

Edit:

These are my model classes:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('left', 'right', 'user');

    public function producto(){
        return $this->hasMany('Product');

    }
}


class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('nombre', 'category', 'proveedor', 'costo', 'precio', 'tiempo_de_elaboracion', 'usuario', 'peso', 'precio_minimo', 'destacado');

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function image(){
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$products` a collection or an array? Also wouldn't it be nicer to select the products right away from the db? I'm sure that has to be possible somehow

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm learning still. I have an entity called Product, I hope it helps.

Comment: Can update your question with your Product model and your Category model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I looked for the branches first and put them into a list:

```
$array = $branches->lists('id');
```

And then, I looked for the products in this branches:

```
$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $array)->paginate(24);
```

Sorry for the dumb question, I was applying the wrong focus

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this in a much nicer way. Instead of first getting the categories and then loading the products for each category, you can query all products that are in the category.

We will use `whereHas` that allows us to set where conditions on relationships. [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

```
$products = Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($category){
    $q->whereBetween('left', array($category->left, $category->right));
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To push items into the array:

```
$products = array();
foreach ($branches as $branch) {
    $products[] = $branch->product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What relationship between branch and product? HasMany I think? How do you defined this relationship in Branch model? If you preserve logical syntax in it definition, it should be called as `$branch->products` in your code...

If everything is good and data is retrieved, use

```
$products = [];
foreach ($branches as $branch) {
    $products += $branch->products;
}
```